# How javascript receive callbacks after request when it is single threaded?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I know that there is similar topics, but I cannot find answer to the following question. Why The first piece of code executes callback while the second doesn't.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log("Request is ready");
}
xmlHttp.open("GET", "www.google.com", true);

var result = 0;

while(1 < 5) {
}
```

In the code above `Request is ready` is printed. But with the following code:

```
    setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("Test")
    }, 5)

    while (1 < 5) {

   }
```

`Test` is not printed. Why this is happening? I thought that `onreadystatechange` will push this function to be executed when the request is ready, but because we have an infinite loop the looper will not check the queue (because looper loops on the main thread and it is busy). This logic works on the second example, but not on the first. Obviously I am missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no asynchronous event in the first case: `open` triggers the first state change and **synchronously** calls the `onreadystatechange` callback.

The `"Request is ready"` log is done **before** the loop is entered.

If you add the `xmlHttp.send` and you call a non cached URL, you'll notice the callback isn't called for the other changes, because those ones are really asynchronous.

Comment: True. The onreadystatechange event will only be called for the first change. Other calls, for instance when the request is completely done, you won't get another event.

Comment: Thank you very much. But stil I thing that this change is sent to the queue after the work currently doing is done. And obviously I am not right. So I thing that when open is called this will sent the action to do to the queue, but instead of this it is executed immediately?

Comment: @DPM Yes, the event queue isn't used for the first change. More recent API are more consistent in how they handle events, the rule being that something that can be asynchronous must always be asynchronous (see [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for example). In the old times, many devs were of the opinion it was preferable to avoid callback queues for performance reasons (jQuery for example was just recently fixed to have Defferred *always* be resolved asynchronously).